# On generating Euler Square of index q, q-1 (where q is any prime power)

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Can somebody help me in generating Euler Square of index q, q-1 (where q is any prime power). Also, kidly tell me if there is any code availeble for generating the stated Euler Square. The details of Euler Squares may be found at: www.jstor.org/stable/1967920‎
(In particular, I fail to understand A and B in section-4 of above link).

Comment: It might go better if you were to include a definition of Euler square in the body opf your question.

Comment: Clarifications:  (1) I can't get the link above to work.  (2) If, by "Euler square of index $q$", you mean a pair of orthogonal latin squares of size $q$ as in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSquare.html, then your question is not really of research interest; sorry.  This is just basic finite fields. (3) On the other hand, a pair of orthogonal latin squares of order $q-1$ may be a nontrivial matter (but still about 50 years old).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 'Euler Squares' by Harris F. MacNeish is available on google. This paper guarantees the existence/construction of Euler Square of index q,q-1 for prime or prime power q. I fail to understand it. I am interested in  generating it (or coding it up).  Quite frankly, I have just started reading papers on this topic.